# Saving a URL address NETCore

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

How can I save the website someone is accessing using NET?

The company that I work have multiple landing pages, I need to check wich one the user is accessing after he accept or not the cookie policy  and save it on a postgres database.

Right now I'm using this to get the user IP and it is working fine.

```
historicoCookie.EnderecoIp = this.HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress.ToString();
```

Is there anything like that to get the URl the user is accessig?

Comment: Write some code.

Comment: For further guidance, read https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to get it from the Request object

```
var requestUrl = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions.UriHelper.GetDisplayUrl(this.Request);
```

Comment: I also find a different way to work with it

 if (Request.Headers.ContainsKey("Origin"))
            {
                historicoCookie.Origem = Request.Headers["Origin"];
        
            }